# Mongo Aggregation Count Child Documents (Count Replies For Comments)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection called `comments` where the structure is something like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  slug: 'foo',
  text: 'I am a comment'
}, 
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  slug: 'foo/bar',
  parentSlug: 'foo',
  text: 'I am a reply'
},
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  slug: 'foo/bar/baz',
  parentSlug: 'foo/bar',
  text: 'I am a reply to a reply'
}
```

I want to get the comments for a certain level and add the number of replies to each (where parentSlug is equal to the comment slug).

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  slug: 'foo',
  text: 'I am a comment',
  replyCount: 1
}
```

I think this is possible with Mongo aggregation but am not sure what aggregation stages I need and how they would be structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need [**`$graphLookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) here

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $graphLookup: {
    from: "collection",
    startWith: "$slug",
    connectFromField: "slug",
    connectToField: "parentSlug",
    as: "replyCount",
    maxDepth: 2,
    depthField: "d"
  }},
  { $addFields: {
    replyCount: { $size: "$replyCount" }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P-GYLfE_0Bc)

Comment: After reading more in the docs for the $graphLookup feature it's a really neat! Works a treat though I was stumped for a little why replyCount was always coming back zero - turns out I had to change `from: "collection",` to `from: "comments",` to match the correct collection ‍♂️